# How to configure fabric with SSH key on a Window machine

Tags: python, windows, fabric, ssh-keys

I am using Window machine. and able to execute Fabric commands using `Cygwin-Terminal`.

The problem which i am facing is that i am not able to `set env.key_filename` in my Fabric file.

My ssh Key is stored at location `'C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\SSH_Key.ppk'` , I am providing my ssh key location in my Fabric file as following.

```
env.user = 'User1'

env.key_filename = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\SSH_Key.ppk'
```

And this i strongly believe that i need to copy SSH_Key.ppk file to some other place. But not sure where.

My fabric file location is `'C:\cygwin\home\nikumar\deploy.py'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Cygwin_Terminal the path to the C: drive is /cygdrive/c/
or the path you would need to use inside cygwin would be

```
'/cygdrive/c/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/WinSCP/SSH_Key.ppk'
```

also you will probably also need to export the ppk to an openssh key using puttygen so openssh can read the file.

Comment: Thanks Greg. You are right , i have downloaded puttygen Generator and converted ppk to openssh key. This worked.

Comment: The weird thing for us is that paramiko auto-discovers ~/.ssh/id_rsa and uses it no matter what we put into env.key_filename (and it works if I add id_rsa.pub to authorized_keys, but Fabric refuses to use a .pem file specified any other way).